# agsXMPP OnLogin event not firing Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmpp, google-talk, agsxmpp

I am trying to make an agsXMPP GTalk chat client in Asp.Net but the OnLogin event is just not doing anything at all, I have tried so, so many things...

Can anyone please help me?

Here is the code for the aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
...

using agsXMPP;
using agsXMPP.protocol.client;
using agsXMPP.Collections;
using agsXMPP.protocol.iq.roster;
using System.Threading;

using Microsoft.Win32;

public partial class ChatClient : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private agsXMPP.XmppClientConnection xmppCC = new XmppClientConnection();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void xmpp_OnLogin(object sender)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Succes!" + xmppCC.Authenticated.ToString();
        xmppCC.SendMyPresence();
    }

    string emailAdres; string password;
    protected void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        emailAdres = textEmail.Text; password= textPassw.Text;

        xmppCC = (XmppClientConnection)Application["xmpp"];
        if (xmppCC == null)
        {
            xmppCC = new XmppClientConnection();
            Application["xmpp"] = xmppCC;
        }

        Jid jidSender = new Jid(emailAdres);

        xmppCC.Username = jidSender.User;
        xmppCC.Server = jidSender.Server;
        xmppCC.Password = password;
        xmppCC.AutoResolveConnectServer = true;

        try
        {
            xmppCC.OnLogin += xmpp_OnLogin;
            lblMsg.Text = "";
            xmppCC.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmppCC.Server` is not always equal to `jidSender.Server`, to auto resolve `Server` try this:

```
    emailAdres = textEmail.Text; password= textPassw.Text;
    xmppCC = (XmppClientConnection)Application["xmpp"];
    Jid jidSender = new Jid(emailAdres);
    if (xmppCC == null)
    {
        xmppCC = new XmppClientConnection(jidSender.Server);
        Application["xmpp"] = xmppCC;
    }


    // xmppCC.Username = jidSender.User;
    // xmppCC.Server = jidSender.Server; it will be resolved with AutoResolveConnectServer = true
    // xmppCC.Password = password;
    xmppCC.AutoResolveConnectServer = true;

    xmppCC.OnLogin += s => Debug.WriteLine("Logged in");
    xmppCC.Open(jidSender.User, password);
```

Comment: It's not really doing anything new, only now when I have typed in the address, it saves it somewhere permanent, so when I type in another address, the server stays the same (Eg, I type in x@x.x, then wt@gmail.com, it will turn that into wt@x.x)

Comment: If you are using Google Talk account, then `xx@gmail.com` account should be resolved to `talk.google.com` server

Comment: Where would I be able to see that during debugging?

Comment: I'm not sure you are using agsXMPP right. agsXMPP must open TCP connection to server and maintain it opened. If you instantiate connection on `Web.UI.Page`, it will just destroyed after page loaded.

Comment: It says the ConnectServer is "xmpp.l.google.com"
Also I've been following tutorials on this that do it the same way
Eg. http://forum.ag-software.net/thread/836-ASP-net-example-with-AJAX

Comment: Yes, it is right server, and it will change from time to time.
But using agsXMPP with ASP.NET still unclear for me - your link have exactly the same code as you and it should not work.

Comment: Read my previous comment - **your XMPP/TCP connection just dropped after page loaded**. You need to create connection in the application context or elsewhere connection will stay in memory.

Comment: Isn't that what

`xmppCC = (XmppClientConnection)Application["xmpp"];`

does?

Comment: Ok, maybe it will work, but you cannot assign Text to label without page reload.

Comment: But that's not what's happening here really, because when I put a breaking point on the OnLogin, it just doesn't get there at all, like I'm doing something wrong with the server.

Comment: Check my updated code, I have tested it, and it works.

Comment: It is working now! But I still can't really see if I am logged in or not, the onlogin is not firing still.

Comment: When you hit "Debug" in Visual Studio, you should see "Logged in" in Debug window.

Comment: I am logged in, I can see that in GMail, and I can logout now too, but the OnLogin event is still not firing, however the OnError event fires when I leave the boxes empty,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to combine it with a realtime HTTP channel like SignalR. See also my blog post here:
http://www.ag-software.net/2012/08/20/web-clients-with-matrix-and-signalr/